# Make API call to Machine Learning module on IoT Edge

Tags: api, web-services, machine-learning, azure-iot-edge

I've been able to push down a machine learning module to an IoT edge device as per the below Microsoft tutorial. I am also able to get ML predictions from routing data from the tempSensor simulated data module to the ML module which is great.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-machine-learning

What i would like to do is use the Machine Learning module as a web service on the IoT Edge device - is there a way to target this module using REST etc? Something similar to the below, although i'm pushing down the ML model as a module to the IoT edge device not as a web service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/preview/model-management-service-deploy

EDIT: I'm not looking to deploy a ML image as a web service like the following link using "az ml service create" etc. I would like to deploy the ML image as a module via IoT Edge management and still access it via REST API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/preview/model-management-service-deploy

Cheers,
Com

Comment: All Azure Machine Learning models containerized as Docker-based web services can also run on Azure IoT Edge devices.Have you can refered to [Deploying a Machine Learning Model as a web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/model-management-service-deploy)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i have. 
The workflow here uses this instead: az ml service run realtime -i <service id> -d "etc". I can use this on the Edge device (I assume?) after i set it up as a local environment. This would pull the docker image from the repository directly. The downside of this i believe is you cannot use it in the routing between modules which is in the IoT Edge architecture.

If i use the workflow in pushing a module down via IoT Edge management (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-machine-learning), can i still access the REST service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the REST API for scoring your data in the Docker container on the Azure IOT Edge device can be called directly.  Here is more information on consuming a web service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/preview/model-management-consumption

If you are interested in creating your own custom AI/ML models, I would recommend going through the Azure ML Iris tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/preview/tutorial-classifying-iris-part-1

This will walk you through training a model and operationalizing it to a Docker container.  You can inference by calling the REST API with your data whether the container is deployed to the cloud or on the edge.

Comment: Hi Ted, what if you deploy it as a IoT Edge module like this link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-machine-learning. For context i have gone through these tutorials. The tutorials show how to deploy a web service using "az ml service run realtime" and not as a IoT module which then can integrate with the IoT Edge routing functionality.